# Match regex then count lines for each individual column: AWK

Tags: awk

I want to count the number of instances when value in column 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. satisfies specific condition. The following works for one column and one condition:

```
awk '$2 >= 0.8 { count++ } END { print count }' input.file
```

However, I have some 20 columns and several conditions (e.g., >=0.8, >=0.9, ==1 etc.). There must be a way to print numerous conditions for each line. Essentially, count number of instances when column 1 satisfies >=0.8, then >=0.9, then ==1, then do the same for column 2 and so on. Awk solution preferred.

```
cat input.file

    Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
Row1    0.5155  0.9793  0.995   0.9569
Row2    0.9799  0.9873  0.9961  0.9619
Row3    0.9732  0.983   0.9961  0.9627
Row4    0.9799  0.9873  0.995   0.9303
Row5    0.9799  0.9873  0.995   0.9303
```

**EDIT**: The file does have column and row titles - essentially as above but with some 20 columns and about 9,000 rows. Desired output:

```
Column1: >=0.8: 7821, >=0.9: 1268, ==1: 36
Column2: >=0.8: 8541, >=0.9: 7400, ==1: 1560
Column3: etc
```

Actual formatting of the output can differ, obviously.

Thanks!

Comment: does your file include the header `Column1 Column2 ...` or the 1st column `Row1 / Row2 / ....`? if not then please update the question to show the actual contents of the file sans any extra labels

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: please update the question with a set of test conditions (eg, 2 columns, 2 tests per column), the code you've attempted to use to address the requirements, the (wrong?) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output

Comment: Question updated. I don't have attempted code beside what I already included - unfortunately, it's way beyond my bash/awk skills. Hopefully, it's more clear now.

Comment: The desired output you provide has to be **exactly** the output you want **from the input you provide** otherwise it's only partially useful in demonstrating your needs and we can't copy/paste it to test a potential solution against. It won't be missing any columns or rows and it won't contain any ellipses nor `etc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v eq='1' -v ge='0.8,0.9' '
    BEGIN{
        eqNum=split(eq,eqArr,",")
        geNum=split(ge,geArr,",")
    }
    NR>1{
        for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){
            for(j=1; j<=eqNum; j++){
                if ("column "i " == " eqArr[j] in a == 0) 
                    a["column "i " == " eqArr[j]] = 0  
                if($i == eqArr[j]) 
                    a["column "i " == " eqArr[j]]++
            }
            
            for(j=1; j<=geNum; j++){
                if ("column "i " >= " geArr[j] in a == 0) 
                    a["column "i " >= " geArr[j]] = 0 
                if($i >= geArr[j]) 
                    a["column "i " >= " geArr[j]]++
            }
        }
    }
    END{
        asorti(a,b)
        for(i in b) printf "%-20s - counter: %d\n", b[i], a[b[i]]
    }
' input_file

column 2 == 1        - counter: 0
column 2 >= 0.8      - counter: 4
column 2 >= 0.9      - counter: 4
column 3 == 1        - counter: 0
column 3 >= 0.8      - counter: 5
column 3 >= 0.9      - counter: 5
column 4 == 1        - counter: 0
column 4 >= 0.8      - counter: 5
column 4 >= 0.9      - counter: 5
column 5 == 1        - counter: 0
column 5 >= 0.8      - counter: 5
column 5 >= 0.9      - counter: 5


awk -v eq='1' -v ge='0.8,0.9' '
    BEGIN{
        eqNum=split(eq,eqArr,",")
        geNum=split(ge,geArr,",")
    }
    NR>1{
        for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){
            for(j=1; j<=eqNum; j++){
                if ("== " eqArr[j] in a == 0) 
                    a["== " eqArr[j]] = 0  
                if($i == eqArr[j]) 
                    a["== " eqArr[j]]++
            }
            
            for(j=1; j<=geNum; j++){
                if (">= " geArr[j] in a == 0) 
                    a[">= " geArr[j]] = 0 
                if($i >= geArr[j]) 
                    a[">= " geArr[j]]++
            }
        }
    }
    END{
        asorti(a,b)
        for(i in b) printf "%-10s - counter: %d\n", b[i], a[b[i]]
    }
' input_file

== 1       - counter: 0
>= 0.8     - counter: 19
>= 0.9     - counter: 19
```

Answer (score 1):

[TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr) `awk` macro:

```
~
$ txr cond.tl data
values greater than 0.97 by column:
4 5 5 0
```

Code in `cond.tl`:

```
(awk
  ;; variable binding
  (:let (rows (build-list))) ;; rows is a list builder

  ;; main actions
  ((= nr 1) (next))          ;; skip first record (headings)
  ((fconv - : r)             ;; convert 2nd and remaining fields as float
   (pop f)                   ;; remove first field (label)
   rows.(add f))             ;; add all fields to row collector

  ;; end actions: transpose rows to cols, do some calculations
  (:end (let ((cols (transpose rows.(get))))
          (put-line `values greater than 0.97 by column:`)
          [apply prn (mapcar (op count-if (op < 0.97)) cols)])))
```

For multiple conditions, we would want to wrap that last bit of logic in a function, since the `apply`, `mapcar` and `count-if` pattern would be common to them; all that varies is the condition being tested and counted.

I did exactly such a thing in the following program, which shows a different solution that avoids using the `awk` macro:

```
$ txr cond2.tl < data
# of values x in each column such that (> x 0.97):
4 5 5 0
# of values x in each column such that (< x 0.95):
1 0 0 2
# of values x in each column such that (<= 0.95 x 0.97):
0 0 0 3
```

Code:

```
;; macro which counts how many elements in each column
;; satisfy the expression expr, which uses the variable x
;; to refer to the value.
(defmacro operation (cols expr)
  ^(progn
     (format t "# of values x in each column such that ~s:\n" ',expr)
     (put-line `@(mapcar (op count-if (lambda (x) ,expr)) ,cols)`)))

;; main line
(flow (get-lines)                        ;; get lines of stdin as strings
  (drop 1)                               ;; drop the first one
  (mapcar (opip                          ;;   map all lines through this pipe:
            (tok #/[^ ]+/)               ;;   tokenize each line
            (drop 1)                     ;;   drop first token
            (mapcar tofloat)))           ;;   convert rest to float numbers
  transpose                              ;; transpose rows to columns
  (let cols)                             ;; bind to cols variable (TXR 291)
  (progn                                 ;; eval forms sequentially as program
    (operation cols (> x 0.97))          ;;   count col values greater than 0.97
    (operation cols (< x 0.95))          ;;   count x < 0.95
    (operation cols (<= 0.95 x 0.97))))  ;;   count 0.95 <= x <= 0.97
```

Comment: Thanks! First time I hear about TXR. I wanted to point out that installation using homebrew failed, and installing the binaries for Linux got me a "segmentation error" when trying to run (which is probably something on my end). Anyway - just wanted to point that out. Awk works fine :)